# TypeError is not thrown in Redis message event

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, node-redis

I'm trying to implement an event system.

Node subscribes to Redis channel, receives message and calls non-existent method in object.

Complete code is here. Simple.
http://pastebin.com/8XnbaepE  
Why error is not thrown?

I don't understand this behaviour.

Another strange problem is that after first time publishing message to channel next times when different channel and payload passed, the function arguments are old one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in node redis module.

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/pull/361

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an exception, this means node-redis caught it, and did not re-throw.  This is actually a good practice in async i/o code as this will prevent node from exiting and killing your server.

Most likely you'll see your error if you register a callback on error.

```
sub.on("error", function(err) {
  // deal with error
  // ...
}
```

Comment: the error is discarded here: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/lib/parser/javascript.js#L214.  probably to wrap the on code within a try catch.

Comment: Yep. I just found myself that part. I think the right way is to do this.emit('error', err); there and catch that in application level.

Comment: I've reported it to node_redis bugtracker.
https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/377